# How to perform a null check in an equality operator overload

Tags: c#, .net, operator-overloading

I've written a simple class that wraps an XElement. I want to pass through equality operations to the wrapped instance. So I wrote this:

```
public class XmlWrapper
{
    protected readonly XElement _element;

    public XmlWrapper(XElement element)
    {
        _element = element;
    }

    static public bool operator == (XmlWrapper lhs, XmlWrapper rhs)
    {
        return lhs._element.Equals(rhs._element);
    }

    static public bool operator != (XmlWrapper lhs, XmlWrapper rhs)
    {
        return !(lhs == rhs);
    }
}
```

This seems straightforward, but actually it throws an exception for a very simple null check:

```
    XmlWrapper wrapper = new XmlWrapper(someElement);
    XmlWrapper nullWrapper = null;

    if (wrapper != nullWrapper) Console.WriteLine("Wrapper is not null"); //This line throws
```

It's because the equality operator is receiving null for one of its arguments and therefore can't retrieve the wrapped XElement. So the obvious thought is to add a null check, like this:

```
static public bool operator == (XmlWrapper lhs, XmlWrapper rhs)
{
    if (lhs == null && rhs == null) return true;
    if (lhs == null || rhs == null) return false;
    return lhs._element.Equals(rhs._element);
}
```

However, this results infinite recursion, because the `==` operator calls the `==` operator again.

If this were any other kind of method, I'd just call the base, but that doesn't work with an operator, e.g. you can't write

```
if (lhs base.== rhs)
```

So how do I get around this? Is there some way to call the base `==` operator from within the overloaded operator body? Or some other way to perform the null check without using `==`?

Here is the [code on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZsLn1r).

Comment: Check `ReferenceEquals(null, lhs)`

Comment: Also ideally you should be overriding `Equals` method

Comment: Provided a full answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57733628/5233410)

Comment: Note that complete answer is provided in FM ["Guidelines for Overriding Equals() and Operator =="](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms173147(v=vs.90)), in particular: "If both are null, or both are same instance, return true. If one is null, but not both, return false." 
`if (System.Object.ReferenceEquals(a, b)) ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static bool operator == (XmlWrapper lhs, XmlWrapper rhs)
{
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(lhs, null) && Object.ReferenceEquals(rhs, null))
    {
       return true;
    }

    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(lhs, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(rhs, null))
    {
       return false;
    }

    return lhs._element.Equals(rhs._element);
}
```

Comment: Take a look at @nkosi's answer as well.  Once you start implementing the concept of equality comparison, you really need to go whole hog (==, Equals, GetHashCode, etc.)

Comment: I think Rufus L's answer is cleaner, plus it won't throw if `lhs._element` is null (there's no guard against null in the contructor).

Answer (score 2):

This should provide the desired behavior.

Also note that if overriding equality you need to override `GetHashCode`

```
public class XmlWrapper : IEquatable<XmlWrapper> {
    protected readonly XElement _element;

    public XmlWrapper(XElement element) {
        _element = element ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(element));
    }

    static public bool operator ==(XmlWrapper lhs, XmlWrapper rhs) {
        return Equals(lhs, rhs);
    }

    static public bool operator !=(XmlWrapper lhs, XmlWrapper rhs) {
        return !Equals(lhs, rhs);
    }

    public override string ToString() {
        return _element != null ? _element.ToString() : this.GetType().FullName;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() {
        return _element.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) {
        return obj is XmlWrapper other && Equals(other);
    }

    public bool Equals(XmlWrapper other) {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        return _element.Equals(other._element);
    }
}
```

It is worth noting this implementation is specific to reference types.  Since `XmlWrapper` is a reference type.

Comment: I think `operator ==` is a little overdone (compared to Rufus L's version) but it's not missing anything and the whole thing looks pretty robust now.

Comment: Taking advantage of the static `object.Equals(object,object)` method... clever. But I think it's now worth noting in the answer that this implementation is specific to reference types. A value type would've been fine the way you had `operator ==` before, calling `lhs.Equals(rhs)`. Since `XmlWrapper` is a reference type, this is a good way to go, but you wouldn't want someone to blindly copy this for a value type. `lhs` and `rhs` would be boxed and never compare reference-equal to each other or null, and then it ends up in `Equals(object)` anyway.

Comment: To summarize, I think it's good but it's worth noting (perhaps in a comment) that it's specific to reference types so it doesn't get used on value types.

Answer (score 1):

You can shorten the code down to one line using the ternary operator:

```
static public bool operator == (XmlWrapper lhs, XmlWrapper rhs)
{
    return lhs is null ? rhs is null : !(rhs is null) && lhs._element == rhs._element;
}
```

Which says, "if lhs is null, return true if rhs is null or false if rhs is not null. Otherwise (if lhs is not null), return true if rhs is not null and their elements are equals, else return false."

Comment: Putting my code reviewer hat on... That code is not easily decipherable.  Wordier code that more clearly expresses your intent and the behavior is much easier to read and more maintainable in the long run.

Comment: This `operator ==` is defined for that type so it calls back into it. StackOverflowException. That's why Mads Torgersen says to use `is null` instead of `== null`: it's always a reference check and always avoids overloaded operators. It's `ReferenceEquals` without the method call.

Comment: @flydog57 i guess I've been reading code too long, it's extremely clear to me!

Comment: The `lhs == null` will continually call into this operator. It's `return op_Equality(lhs, null) ?...;` which is the very static method you're defining here.

Comment: Only because I've been bitten by it in unit tests! You don't unlearn that lesson easily.

Comment: If you want to avoid the awkward `!(...)`, instead of `!(rhs is null) && lhs._element == rhs._element`, you can do either `rhs is XmlWrapper && lhs._element == rhs._element` or `rhs is XmlWrapper right && lhs._element == right._element`.

Comment: You can actually shorten this to `return lhs?.Equals(rhs) ?? rhs is null;` if `public bool Equals(XmlWrapper? other)` is defined (which it SHOULD be!)

Answer (score 0):

You can apply Elvis operator and null-coalescing operator as well to make it working.

```
    static public bool operator == (XmlWrapper lhs, XmlWrapper rhs)
    {
        if (lhs?._element == null && rhs?._element == null) return true;
        return lhs?._element?.Equals(rhs?._element) ?? false;
    }
```